# How can I select each shapes in loop?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Powerpoint 2010

I am trying to select on each new shape in the loop. But not all shapes in loop are selected. Always only the last shape is selected. What is wrong?

Thank you

```
Private Sub AddShapeRectangleOnSelectedText()

  Dim oText As TextRange
  Dim linesCount As Integer
  Dim myDocument As Slide
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim s As Shape

  ' Get an object reference to the selected text range.
  Set oText = ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange
  Set myDocument = ActiveWindow.View.Slide
  linesCount = oText.Lines.Count

  For i = 1 To linesCount
    Set s = myDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
    oText.Lines(i).BoundLeft, oText.Lines(i).BoundTop, oText.Lines(i).BoundWidth, oText.Lines(i).BoundHeight)

    With s
     .Select
     .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
     .Fill.Solid
     .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 153)
     .Fill.Transparency = 0.7
     .Line.Visible = msoFalse
     .Line.Transparency = 0#
    End With
  Next
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select` has an optional parameter to indicate whether the selection should replace the previous selection or not...

you can modify your code like this

```
.Select IIf(i = 1, True, False)
```